# Location of default Background Images

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, theme, image

I'm relatively new at SharePoint development and am currently suffering from a problem where the default images for backgrounds aren't linking anymore, forcing me to 'remove' the image before applying a new look.

I was wondering where the images are stored on the server so I can make my self a copy (and give the images a few tweaks as well) and to allow me to set the path to the new image.

Edit: I am using SP 2013 Server Standard(V 15.0.4569.1506 On-Site) the images in question are the ones found under Change the Look (such as the defualt background Image for the Sea Monster Scheme, etc). If people happen to know the location for the other default images that would be nice as well (Such as the arrow symbol for drop downs or the camera picture for the newsfeed)

Comment: pls mention the version of SharePoint you are using. please elaborate on background images.

Comment: Post has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your SharePoint server, you can find many of the images under the following locations:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\THEMES[THEME NAME]